# Display an Animated Tray Icon using Shell_NotifyIcon in Delphi Application

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, system-tray

I want my Delphi Application to show an Animated Tray Icon in Notification Area. I also searched about that but I only got results for `TTrayIcon` which I don't use.

I use `Shell_NotifyIcon` and can't figure out how to animate a Tray Icon in Notification Area. The Timer `(TTimer)` which is used to set an Animate Interval for this should be able to be stopped and started at anytime.

The problem is I don't know how to start the `TTimer` after the first restore of the Form done.

I mean a user opened my Program, and minimized it to System Tray, its System Tray Icon was animated well, and user restored it for some reason again, and he again minimize it to System Tray and then **System Tray Icon Animation and `TTimer`should be able to start again and should not be displayed like a normal System Tray Icon which doesn't Animate.**

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: To enable the TTimer set TTimer.Enabled to true

Comment: use Tcooltrayicon. it already has support for animation. http://subsimple.com/delphi.php

Answer (score 6):

In fact, I did not understand your question very well, but if you are referring to activate TTimer When you restore the program and disable it when you Minimized

You can use  "ApplicationEvents" :

1. OnMinimize:

   ```
   procedure TForm1.ApplicationEvents1Minimize(Sender: TObject);
   begin
     Timer1.Enabled:=False;
   end;
   ```
2. OnRestore:

   ```
   procedure TForm1.ApplicationEvents1Restore(Sender: TObject);
   begin
     Timer1.Enabled:=True;
   end;
   ```

Good Luck.